# A function which is R-integrable but does not have an antiderivative

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

How is it possible that this function: $$ 
    f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0, & -1\le x < 0 \\
         1, & 0\le x \le 1\end{array}\right. 
$$

is *R-integrable* in $[-1,1]$ , but does not have an antiderivative there?

From the mean value theorem for derivatives, it can not be that the derivative has a jump at 0 , so it can not have a antiderivative?

Comment: Why would $1$ not be the integral of this function? That's what it is at least for Riemann and Lebesgue integration.

Comment: This function is Riemann integrable and its integral is 1.

Comment: I think you are confusing integral with antiderivative.

Comment: yes i meant the german word stammfunktion which is antiderivative in english.... sry

Comment: What about: $$
    F(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 0, & -1\le x < 0 \\
         x, & 0\le x \le 1\end{array}\right. 
$$ ?

Comment: @Darius, the function you gave is not differentiable! To see this check the differential quotient at point $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to see that $f$ doesn't have an antiderivative, is to use [Darboux's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29) which states that every derivative has the intermediate value property, even if it (the derivative) is not continuous.

Answer (score 2):

A function does not have to be differentiable in order to be Riemann integrable.

Recall one more time Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability from my previous answer: a function $f: [a, b] \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ is Riemann integrable if and only if it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere on $[a,b]$.

In the present case, $|f(x)| \leq 1$ on $[-1, 1]$. Furthermore, it is continuous everywhere except at the point $x = 0$, and the set $\{0\}$ has Lebesgue measure zero. Hence $f$ is continuous almost everywhere on $[-1,1]$.

It follows that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[-1,1]$, and of course its integral is $1$ (the area under the graph of $f$).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps say it this way:  If
$$
F(x) := \int_{-1}^x f(t) dt
$$
then we may say $F$ is an indefinite integral of $f$.  Certainly $F$ exists.  But $F$ fails to be differentiable at the point $x=0$.  One of the proofs of the Fundamental Theorem of Caluculs will, indeed, show that $F'(x) = f(x)$ at every point where $f$ is continuous.  But $x=0$ escapes from that criterion.

Comment: Which proof of the fundamental Theorem of Calculus od you mean?