# Differentiable $f$, $g$, such that $f^{'} g$ does not have an antiderivative

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Do there exist real functions $f$ and $g$, both differentiable, such that $f^{'} g$ does not have an antiderivative?

Comment: You could take $f(x) = x$ and $g$ to be any differentiable function that doesn't have an (elementary, I suppose?) antiderivative, say $g(x) = \exp(-x^2)$.

Comment: Well yes of course if $f^{'} g$ is continuous then an antiderivative exists, I'm wondering about the case when it's not. And any antiderivative, not necessarily a closed form one.

Comment: Two related questions: 1. [Is it necessary that every function is a derivative of some function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760698/is-it-necessary-that-every-function-is-a-derivative-of-some-function), 2. [Continuity $\Rightarrow$ Intermediate Value Property. Why is the opposite not true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622076/continuity-rightarrow-intermediate-value-property-why-is-the-opposite-not-tr)

Comment: See: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm88/fm88118.pdf